# Run a shell script from ruby

Tags: iphone, ios, ruby, shell, frank

I am doing iOS testing using Frank.  It is a ruby gem that uses Cucumber as well.  I have a "Given" step that checks whether the app is running or if it has crashed.  If my step finds that it has crashed I would like to launch the app again.  I launch the app using a shell script which is stored somewhere near the cucumber .feature files.

How can I call a script from that step definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this a few different ways

```
Kernel.system "command"
%x[command]
`command`
```

Comment: By the way, you don't need the `Kernel.`; that module is already included into Object by default. Or something like that.

Comment: Yes, unless you have a local method with the same name, the `Kernel` prefix is redundant, however it's relevant for looking up documentation. Those magical methods that show up everywhere are usually in Kernel.

Comment: It's always good to namespace, for the exact reason @tadman stated.

Answer (score 2):

As other answers suggested, there are many ways of executing shell scripts from Ruby, but they're all not created equal. I'll try to explain all methods i know in more detail.

## Backticks

```
`command arg1 arg2`
%x(command arg1 arg2)
```

Runs the command in a subshell and returns the output of the command. The command and its arguments are provided as a string delimited by backticks. An alternative syntax is `%x(...)` which serves to avoid escaping issues, e.g. when you want to execute a command that contains backticks itself. The parentheses can be replaced by other delimiters such as `[]`, `{}`, `!!`, … in order to be able to work around just about any escaping issue.

Stderr is printed as normal, Stdout is suppressed. Returns the stdout output of the command. This means you can use the backtick notation to get the output of a command into a variable for further processing.

## Kernel.exec

```
exec("command arg1 arg2")
exec("command", "arg1", "arg2")
```

Replaces the current process by running the command. The command and its arguments are provided as a normal string or as a comma delimited list of strings. Can be useful if you already have a list of arguments as an array. Output is left as is, i.e. will be printed to the console as if the command was run directly.

## Kernel.system

```
system("command arg1 arg2")
system("command","arg1 arg2")
```

Like `Kernel.exec` but runs in a subshell again. Returns `true` if the process exited correctly (status 0), `false` otherwise. This works great inside `if`-statements.

## Kernel.spawn

```
pid = spawn("command")
# do other stuff
Process.wait(pid)
```

Similar to `Kernel.system` but will spawn a child process to run the specified command. The parent process will thus not wait for the command to finish executing unless `Process.wait` is used. The return value is the PID of the spawned process.

## IO.popen

```
io = IO.popen("command")
IO.popen("command") {|io| ... }
```

Runs the command in a child process again but allows for greater control over the IO. The child processes' stdout and stdin are connected to an IO object that is either accessible as the return value or a block parameter. If obtained via return value, the IO object should be closed after using it with `io.close`.

Answer (score 1):

## Open3

For use-cases more advanced than [`system`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system) or [`IO.popen`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html#method-c-popen), you can use [Open3](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) from the Ruby standard library. Its [`popen3`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3) method lets you manually interact with the stdin, stdout, and stderr of the child process. Open3’s [`popen2`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen2) method is the same except it doesn’t give you stderr. An example of using `popen2`:

```
require 'open3'

Open3.popen2("wc -c") do |stdin, stdout, status_thread|
  stdin.print "answer to life the universe and everything"
  stdin.close
  p stdout.gets #=> "42\n"
end
```

Answer (score -1):

[Here are some nice ways](http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html). Backticks are probably the least intrusive. But beware: as pointed out by tadman, `exec` terminates the calling process, which can be averted by creating a child process or using `system`.

Comment: Great link! you Goggled.. :)

Comment: Remember that [`exec`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-exec) effectively terminates the calling process so you'll never get a response, so it's probably last in that list. Why is it the most "readable"?

Comment: I didn't realize that it does that... As for readability, someone not familiar with Ruby would probably figure out what it does pretty quickly, as opposed to the backticks.

Comment: What they won't figure out is that it'll terminate your process and never return anything, so it should really be avoided. Backticks are something that Ruby has in common with Perl, so it's not entirely unexpected.

Comment: Alright, I've updated the answer to reflect this information. Thanks for your input! :)